# Use htaccess file to redirect all traffic to index.php and non-www to www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've looked at other questions and none seem to address what I want to do. Currently I have the following in my .htaccess file to redirect all non-www traffic to www:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This works fine. Whether the file exists or not, if someone tries to access example.com or example.com/page-not-found it will make a permanent redirect to www.example.com or www.example.com/page-not-found.

I want to change the way the website runs and have all requests get routed through a specific file (for example index.php in the main directory). What should happen is that if someone goes to `www.example.com/any-page`, it will still show `www.example.com/any-page`, but I will be handling it in www.example.com/index.php, so that I can handle all traffic in one file. I can do this with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

However, this will only redirect if the requested folder does not exist (and also it will not change `example.org/any-folder` to `www.example.org/any-folder`.

In short, is there a way of routing all requests through a single file, even if the requested file exists, and to do a 301 redirect for all non-www traffic to www?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. First of all keep your original rule as it was (slightly modified, see below):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

After that, add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

So very similar to what you already had, except:

- removing flags on the last rule that weren't necessary
- adding a check for the host on the second rule
- removing slash on replacement in second rule that is not part of the match in a .htaccess file
- changing the RewriteCond check a little, including redirecting anything that is not www.example.com rather than just example.com. I recommend pointing ww.example.com and similar to your site so spelling mistakes like that get redirected with it (personally I just point *.example.com to my site in most cases).

Let me know any problems.

Comment: What does ```?path=$1``` do? (Do I need it, or can the last line just be ```RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]```?)

Comment: It adds a path parameter to the request with the requested path as the value, missing the opening forward slash. You can leave it off and just access that from environment variables if you like, I think. You are going to need some way to know what was requested. That's the usual way. If you do remove it, you don't need the [QSA] either.

Comment: I don't think there actually is an environment variable you can use to check what the original request was from PHP, since "REQUEST_URI" will get overwritten with index.php, so I think you really need it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for everything except for one specific folder and all it's children? (such as do it for everything on example.com, except for example.com/edit)

Comment: Yes, add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/edit/` just above the last RewriteRule.

Comment: Also, is the redirect here from non-www to www a 301 redirect (SEO question)?

Comment: It is indeed. That is defined by the R=301 flag in the square brackets at the end of the rule. R on its own would mean temporary, as would R=302.